# session state payment

Tags: c#, session-state, payment-processing

We need to store user details between Iframe pages and callbacks. Some details need to be secure and robust as they are for online payments. Either we store the details in our database or in a session. However if the web server goes down or when we publish during the day a user will lose their session. We don't have a web farm so don't need StateServer or SQLServer session states. 
Do we:

1. store details in the database then update after confirmation
2. Store details in session using inproc
3. store details in session using StateServer
4. store details in session using SQLServer
5. pass details to payment provider who can pass them back again.

Comment: Why not use StateServer?  Your concern is about the web server going down and losing in-memory session sate.  If you use StateServer, then you won't have this issue.  It's separate from the web server.

Comment: @casperOne - StateServer is still in-memory, just in a dedicated process instead of the Worker Process. If the State Server Service were to be restarted, then the session state would be gone. SQL Server might be a better option.

Comment: Can you tell me why SQLServer state is better than storing in the database or passing the details direct to the payment provider?

Comment: @vcsjones: Yes, I agree it's in memory but 1) it can be hosted on another machine and 2) he isn't indicating if he needs to protect against the machine going down or the service.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would pass the details direct to the payment provider with a unique payment reference of your own. You can then use that reference to process the payment success when the merchant comes back to you to indicate whether the payment was successful or not.